# How to draw the regression line and the scatterplot between observed and predicted in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

How can I draw observed vs predicted scatterplot in R? I also want to show the regression line in it.

```
library(car)
summary(Prestige)
head(Prestige)
testidx <- which(1:nrow(Prestige)%%4==0)
prestige_train <- Prestige[-testidx,]
prestige_test <- Prestige[testidx,]

model <- glm(prestige~., data=prestige_train)
# Use the model to predict the output of test data 
prediction <- predict(model, newdata=prestige_test)
# Check for the correlation with actual result
plot(prediction, prestige_test$prestige)
```

Edit:

```
abline(model)
```

The above function `abline` does not seem to work. It does draw a line but it seem to be incorrect.

Thanks

Comment: This is a R programming question which is not on-topic here on CrossValidated.

Comment: If the observed and the predicted were very close to each other they would be on a diagonal line on your plot. So you may just want to add abline(0,1) after your plot above?

Comment: What if they are not close?

Comment: The `abline` function called with a `reg` argument like this doesn't do what you apparently think it does. You want arguments `a=0,b=1` instead, as @Seth suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is much need for me to write out the answer in its entirety, when there exists a much more beautiful (and probably more informed) explanation by Hadley Wickham. It is to be found [here](http://stat405.had.co.nz/lectures/23-modelling.pdf) (first part) and [here](http://stat405.had.co.nz/lectures/24-multivariate.pdf) (second, more advanced part).

EDIT: My apologies for not giving a more specific answer from the start. Here how the plot can be made:

```
# define training sample
sample <- sample(nrow(Prestige),40,replace=FALSE)

training.set <- Prestige[sample,]
test.set <- Prestige[-sample,]
model <- glm(prestige ~ .,data=training.set)
# getting predicted values
test.set$predicted <- predict(model,newdata=test.set)

# plotting with base plot 
with(test.set,plot(prestige,predicted))
# plotting with ggplot2
require(ggplot2)
qplot(prestige,predicted,data=test.set)
```

Hope this answers your question.

P.S. The question is indeed more appropriate for SO, it would have been answered there in a matter of minutes :)

Comment: Thanks Maxim. Somehow I couldn't find a place that shows a plot between predicted and observe value.

Comment: @user1140126 My bad. Added a solution. Is that what you want?

Comment: @user1140126 Well, to be honest, maybe it is not a bad idea go actually do something yourself. Like look again at the links I have provided or maybe (a crazy idea) google for "ggplot plot regression". The answers are readily available.

Comment: Searching the term "ggplot plot regression" was helpful. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user1140126 Note that it makes no sense to plot the regression line on the predicted-actual value plot, as the regression line describes the relationship between x and y, while your predicted-actual value plot has y and y-hat. There is just no axis for x in that plot, in other words.